# How to get rid of areas of depression between 2 beveled edges

Tags: bevel

I have a plane having a bevel modifier to the vertices and then a solidify modifier to make it thick and then i have another bevel modifier limit method angle **Angle** and i get these results  , the are between the two edges shoes a depression- [image: v]

How to get rid of this long running depression between the two beveled edges

Comment: Why do you need to use a plane to make that sort of shape?

Comment: will it get solved if i use a cube instead of plane? @J.Chan

Comment: With a cube you could add a loop cut where the depressions are

Comment: @J.Chan used a cube and added a loop cut , problem persists

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? is it supposed to be a bowl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved when i stopped using Harden Normals option in bevel modifier that made the bevel stand out and make the depression